# With Axis2, is there any way to receive angular form data with file upload?

Tags: angular, apache-axis

I'm now using angular11 in my website, which access the server-side axis2 webservice to get/post data.Everything goes well with normal http request, but I cannot find any solution to post my form data with file upload to the axis2 webservice. Is there any sample to show how to get binary upload file data in axis2 webservice?

Here is my angular code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.authorForm.get('file').value);
formData.append('authorCode', authorCode);
```

the file object can be properly shown in browser console.

code in service.ts

```
return this.http.post(this.adminAuthorWebServiceURL + '/updateAuthorTest', formData)
  .pipe(map(Util.extractData))
  .pipe(catchError(Util.handleHttpError)
  );
```

and what should i do to receive these data in Axis2 Webservice?